# What does it mean when we say tomcat server is "running". What exactly is running behind the scenes

Tags: java, tomcat, webserver

What does it mean that tomcat server has started. I know the uses of tomcat but what does it mean that a server is running. And what happens when we stop tomcat. I am not looking for the request response uses of tomcat. I want to know what the "running" of  tomcat server means

Comment: Usually? That the server is available and listening for incoming client requests. Contrast with "not running". Clients that attempt to connect will eventually time-out and fail.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes but what Is happening in server behind the scenes when we say "server is available" is my doubt. We start tomcat so what is happening for it to be available. What happens when we stop it that it stops listening to requests

Comment: [How does Apache Tomcat work internally?](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Apache-Tomcat-work-internally)

Comment: @Spectric I would like to know why tomcat does/doesnot accept requests when we start/stop it. What exactly makes it available/not-available to handle requests. Is it like when we open a word doc and close it ? Memory is allocated to tomcat and deallocated when we stop it? I want to know the meaning behind "server is running"

Answer (score 2):

At a very high level in layman's terms, when Tomcat starts, it calls the Operating System and says "if you get an incoming TCP/IP connection on port 8080<sup>1</sup>, please give it to me", then just sits there and waits for the OS to hand over incoming connections.

When you stop Tomcat, that request to the OS is cancelled, and the Tomcat process terminates.

While Tomcat is *running*, any incoming request is sent to Tomcat, which will handle the request to the best of its ability.

When Tomcat is *stopped*, there is no registered programs for handling an incoming request, so incoming requests are rejected by the OS.

<sup>*1) Port number varies, but 8080 is a common default value*</sup>

Comment: Thankyou. That clears a few of my doubts. Can u also pls explain what you mean by "sits and waits for requests" . So is any code constantly running ?

Comment: @Greg No, it really just sits there *idle*, doing nothing. It makes a "get next request" call to the OS, and that call will not return until a request is available. The OS just puts the call aside, and will pick it up when a request arrives. It's like when you get put on hold on your phone. You just sit there awaiting until someone is ready to talk to you.